# Android LinearLayout and RecyclerView BottomNavigation Alignment

Tags: android, kotlin

so I can't figure out how to align my bottom navigation in a LinearLayout under a RecyclerView. The items are RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".CategoryActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
               app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The navigation should be always at the bottom.

Comment: use the relative layout as parent and assign         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 true to navigation view

Comment: But then my RecyclerView is wrong again..

Comment: modified your layout, check the below answer, if it solves, then mark as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is your layout, it should work as you expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try adding this:

android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change to `RelativeLayout`, set this attribute to the `RecyclerView`:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This way the `RecyclerView` will take all the available space pushing the `BottomNavigationView` to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't adjust your `BottomNavigationView` properly inside `LinearLayout`. If there are so many items in your `RecyclerView` then `BottomNavigationView` will be hidden at the bottom. So you must use `RelativeLayout` to align it at the bottom and other layouts above of `BottomNavigationView`. Please check the bellow modified layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```